# Is it possible to use Wubi to download an older version?

Tags: installation, wubi

Ubuntu installer for Windows doesn't give us an option of downloading older versions of Ubuntu. Can we have an option to download older versions of Ubuntu, 8.04.1 or later versions ? By default Ubuntu installer for Windows downloads latest version of Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

The ubuntu version to download is hard coded into the wubi.exe

You can download older versions from sourceforge

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wubi/files/Wubi/

I would use http://sourceforge.net/projects/wubi/files/Wubi/Wubi-8.04.503/Wubi-8.04.1-beta-rev503.exe/download

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install an older version of Ubuntu then first manually download the ISO  from ubuntu.com

Then follow these steps:

1. Disconnect the internet
2. Create a folder on desktop. Name it "Ubuntu Setup"
3. Put the ISO and Wubi.exe into the folder "Ubuntu Setup"
4. Run Wubi (Double click it )

Wubi will automatically detect the ISO and present you the Installation Wizard.

Comment: The version for `wubi.exe` should match the version of the ISO being used (i.e., of Ubuntu being installed). Old `wubi.exe`s remain officially available. (They will not be able to install Wubi if the files have been moved to the `old-releases` server, but the right version of `wubi.exe` should still used for any ISO version.)